# How do we pass a dynamic coulmn in existing dataframe sparksql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like add a new column that contains current timestamp  in a existing sql query in a dataframe . I don't want to write a function directly in sql query .

```
 val sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 val currentTime= new Date();
 val strDate = sdfDate.format(currentTime);
 val resultDF = sqlContentext.sql("""SELECT
                                          id,
                                          name,
                                          city,
                                         "$strDate" AS process_time 
                                          FROM TEMP""".stripMargin).show(1)

             +-----------------  +--------+-------+----------+
             |         id|             name  |    city|   process_time|
             +--------------------+----------+--------------------+----
             |dfgsywo/yyMSv...|  Surender|     CHN|    $strDate|
```

I tried $strDate  and '$strDate'  as well. But they give error .

Could someone help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
val resultDF = sqlContentext.sql(s"""SELECT
                                          id,
                                          name,
                                          city,
                                         "$strDate" AS process_time 
                                          FROM TEMP""".stripMargin).show(1)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked!..Thanks much!

Comment: Welcome. Glad I could help.